# .Net framework 3.5 and 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5

I have a .net 3.5 application with mvc2.0 used.
Will it work in a server with 4.0 with mvc2.0 with out .net 3.5 framework?

Do I need to make any changes in config?

Comment: We can't say without the source code, you should just test it.

Comment: In general, .NET is highly backwards compatible. So everything that works seemlessly on newer versions of the framework. But still, you will always have to test this. You can't take this for granted. But you might need to make changes in your config file.